# SQL request put values ​in columns

Tags: sql

```
SELECT table1.id,
       SUM(table2.column="n1"),
       SUM(table2.column ="n2")
FROM table1
     INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id 
GROUP BY r.id
```

I have this sql query that works. In column table2 I have 100 different values ​​(including "n1" and "n2"). Is there a way to do the same thing as this query by selecting the 100 values ​​of table2.column (except copy them by hand).

```
SUM (table2.column = "n1"), SUM (table2.column = "n2"), ..., SUM (table2.column = "n100")
```

Comment: Unless you have a column named `"n1"` that is invalid SQL. Which DBMS product are you using? Are you maybe looking for the `filter` condition? `sum(x) filter (where ...)`?

Comment: You've tagged 2 different RDBMS here; MySQL and SQL Server. i've removed both of these, as the conflict. Please it your post and tag only the RDBMS you are using. As for for you question; yes you need to write them out. Otherwise you could use dynamic SQL to create the statement, but without knowing what RDBMS you are using that will be hard. I doubt it's SQL Server as `SUM(table2.column="n1")` isn't valid syntax (but is that really valid MySQL syntax?).

Comment: I had this same problem. It's hard for users to interpret but basically Alix is saying I want to select Sum(table2.n1),Sum(table2.n2)... Sum(table2.n100).. Not easily possible that I know of... Programming or excel is your friend to auto generate the 100 columns needed in the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Best advise I can give you is to build a small program to build the query and copy the output.
You can run the below code for free online at [this site](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        if(i==99)
        {
          printf("SUM(table2.column%d)\r\n",i);          
        }
        else
        {
          printf("SUM(table2.column%d),\r\n",i);          
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It will generate the SQL for your 100 columns automatically for you, without you manually having to copy and paste if the columns are ordered sequentially.

```
SUM(table2.column0),                                                                                                                                                                        
SUM(table2.column1),                                                                                                                                                                        
SUM(table2.column2),                                                                                                                                                                        
SUM(table2.column3),    ....                                                                                                                                                                    
SUM(table2.column99)
```